# Proof of Convergence Based on Monotonicity and a Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**Theorem:** Let the series $a_n$ be monotonous upward and $b_n$ be bounded.
Let $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_n-b_n}=0$, then $b_n$ converges.

I managed to prove by negation that $a_n$ is bounded and therefore converges. I can see why $b_n$ has to converge as well, but I can't seem to prove it formally.

**Proof so far:** Suppose $a_n$ is not bounded. Since it is monotonous upward then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_n=\infty}$. By definition $sup(b_n)$ exists. There exists an $N$ so that for each $n>N, a_n>sup(b_n)$ and so $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_n-b_n>0}$ contradicting the given. Therefore by negation $a_n$ is bounded and so converges. Let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n=L}$.

...

Is that fine so far? Would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M$ be the bound of $b_n$. Then, for sufficiently large $n$:

$a_n -b_n < 1 \implies a_n <1+b_n < 1+M$

So $a_n$ converges. Since $a_n$ and $b_n-a_n$ converges, so does $a_n+ (b_n-a_n)=b_n$